# service which is set as auto is not started when system restarts

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, services

Using the below command created a service in cmd

```
c:\>sc create "DellCare" start= auto displayname= "DellCareService" binpath= "C:\Users\Dev Parzival\Desktop\bat\DellCare\DellCare.bat"

[SC] CreateService SUCCESS
```

When I restarted my laptop the service **DellCare** didn't start.

```
c:\>sc query DellCare

SERVICE_NAME: DellCare
        TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
        STATE              : 1  STOPPED
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 1077  (0x435)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
```

**DellCare.bat**

```
@echo on

cd /D E:\code\pro\DellCare\out

echo Present working directory - %cd%

java --module-path "C:\thirdparty\javafx-sdk-14.0.1\lib;E:\code\pro\DellCare\out;" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.graphics -cp ".;C:\thirdparty\javafx-sdk-14.0.1\lib\*" dellcare.mainclass.MainClass
```

When I tried to start the service manually it gave error

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>sc start dellcare
[SC] StartService FAILED 1053:

The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

Then visited [this link](https://support.threattracksecurity.com/support/solutions/articles/1000071019-error-1053-the-service-did-not-respond-in-a-timely-fashion-when-attempting-to-start-stop-or-pause) and ended up creating **ServicesPipeTimeout** inside **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control** but still when I start dellcare service it gives the same error that the service did not respond in a timely...

Why the service DellCare is not starting and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run just any `exe` or `bat` as a service, because a
[system service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/service-programs)
is specifically written to interface with Windows via a special protocol,
which is used by the `sc` command.

Services are generally written as console applications with the entry point
for a console application as the main function, started by its
[Service Entry Point](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/service-entry-point)
and continuing with the
[ServiceMain Function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/service-servicemain-function).

You may however encapsulate a program or batch file using a program
that does implement the required protocol.

You may use:

- [NSSM - the Non-Sucking Service Manager](http://nssm.cc/)
  (free and open-source)
  Last update from 2017.
- [AlwaysUp](https://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/)
  (commercial)
- Many other
  [alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/nssm--the-non-sucking-service-manager/).

Answer (score 1):

Windows Services usually require some additional configuration rather than one command line as far as I know.

If you try to open `Services` by `services.msc` and start the service just created manually, the following message should appear:

```
Windows could not start the service on Local Computer.

Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

If you only need to run a certain script each time Windows starts (for the current user), you can copy the `.bat` file and paste its shortcut into `"%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"`. Another approach to accessing it is to type `shell:startup` in the Explorer address bar.

Next time the current user logins in, the script will be run automatically.
You can check it's added and enabled via `Task Manager -> Startup`.

Comment: I want like to run it as a service so I can manage it with sc command.